# Determine a value based on the difference between another column of this row and the previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame where each row corresponds to daily figures. There is a column called `price` and I am now attempting to add another column `change` which should be set to 1 if the price for this row is greater than or equal to the price for the previous row, or else 0 if less than.

Desired result:

```
    price    change
0      13       NaN
1      11         0
2      12         1
3      12         1
```

It should work similar to [pandas.DataFrame.pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html)

In fact, I could just create a new column using `pct_change`, then another column set to 0 if `pct_change` is negative and 1 otherwise. Is there a better way to do this in a single step?

Comment: Try `df.price.diff().ge(0).astype(int)`

Comment: df.price.shift()<df.price

Comment: @Wen -- another way of saying `df.price.ge(df.price.shift()).astype(int)`

Comment: @Zero great :-) , BTw , nice to see you back :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can set

`df['change'] = (df.price.diff()>=0).astype(int)`